# Principal server down

Tags: c#, exception

I'm making a program that helps desk workers check in and check out equipment at my college. I could use Enviroment.username, but as a learning experience i want to get the full name of the current user logged in. The one you see when pressing the windows button. So my current playtest code is:

```
PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain);
UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.Current;
string displayName = user.DisplayName;
Console.WriteLine(displayName);
Console.ReadLine();
```

But it gives me a principal server down exception. I imagine this is problem with permissions but i don't even know where to start.

What can i do to get this to work?

Answer (score 2):

If your intention is to display properties for the current user...

`UserPrincipal.Current` grabs the `Principal` running the current thread. If this is intended (ex. using impersonation) then you should have the user data at hand, and not need to set a principal context at all.

```
var up = UserPrincipal.Current;
Console.WriteLine(user.DisplayName);
```

But if the principal running the thread is not the user you want, and you need to gather their account info from a domain (ie. SLaks point), then you'll need to setup a principal context and search it to get the proper UserContext.

```
var pc = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "domainName");
var user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(pc, "samAccountName");
Console.WriteLine(user.DisplayName);
```

You can also use another `IdentityType` if you don't like the samAccountName:

```
var user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(pc, IdentityType.Name, "userName");
// or
var user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(pc, IdentityType.Sid, "sidAsString");
```

If you need to manually authenticate the user first, see **@DJKRAZE's** example using `principalContext.ValidateCredentials()`

Good luck.

Comment: Thank you, I do want the user who is running the thread, but up=UserPrincipal.Current gives me a "PrincipalServerDownException" Which if i catch gives me a "Server could not be contacted" message.

Comment: UserPrincipal is part of DirectoryServices.AccountManagement which is used to work with user/group/computer accounts via Active Directory (DS/LDS). So if your application is not on a domain, you'd have no server with which to look up your current `Principal` object. Without knowing more, I can't help much, but I'm guessing like SLaks, that you using a local account and/or your machine is not connected to an AD domain.

Comment: Yeah its not connected to an AD domain, my school uses a linux domain. But i can still find the display name by going to the start button and seeing my full name. Which means it has to be stored somewhere. Im just trying to figure that out. This method was a way i picked up here at stackoverflow.

Comment: There's your answer; you are getting a local account name then not a Windows domain AD account... change the ContextType appropriately. Hopefully that's a good enough answer for you.

Answer (score 1):

Have you thought about trying something like this

```
bool valid = false;
using (var context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain))
{
    valid = context.ValidateCredentials(username, password);
}
```

if you want to get even more in depth you could do this below

```
using System.Security;
using System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement;

public struct Credentials
{
    public string Username;
    public string Password;
}

public class Domain_Authentication
{
    public Credentials Credentials;
    public string Domain;
    public Domain_Authentication(string Username, string Password, string SDomain)
    {
        Credentials.Username = Username;
        Credentials.Password = Password;
        Domain = SDomain;
    }

    public bool IsValid()
    {
        using (PrincipalContext pc = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, Domain))
        {
            // validate the credentials
            return pc.ValidateCredentials(Credentials.Username, Credentials.Password);
        }
    }
}
```